# Average with ability to configure importance of peak values

Tags: mean, robust, weights

I have list of numbers (about 200 numbers), where almost all numbers are in range of `100` - `10000`, but some numbers (very few, about 5-10 numbers) may have values more than `100000` (see attached graph). I need to get average value from all numbers but pay more attention to more frequent values (from `100` to `10000`), rare values should not be ignored but don't affect the result as much as frequent values. Also, I'd like to configure importance of rare values with coefficient. What formula can I use for this case?[image: values]

Comment: How about a median or weighted average?

Comment: @user2974951 thanks! I think I can use weighted average with Gaussian function as weight, so I'll be able to configure it via `σ` and `μ`, what do you think about it?

Comment: What do you mean by `Gaussian function as weight`?

Comment: @user2974951 I mean calculate weighted arithmetic mean, where weight `w(i) = g(x(i))`, where `g()` - Gaussian function, so formula will be: `sum(g(x(i)) * x(i)) / sum(g(x(i)))`

Comment: I don't really understand, but you can try and see what pops out.